# Failed to restart the network driver

Tags: networking, drivers, server, nfs

I have added recently a IB interface to my Ubuntu machine. My plan is to run NFS with IPoIB. I already have a bond of two gigabit interfaces, configured as round-robin (mode 0). But when I add the infiniband configuration, the network driver fails at raising the interfaces. Here are my configuration files and returns:

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ib0
iface ib0 inet static
address 192.168.3.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.3.255

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary eno1

auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
bond-mode 0
bond-miimon 100
bond-slaves eno1 enp1s0
```

ifconfig:

```
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.148  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::f292:1cff:fee4:ce7e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f0:92:1c:e4:ce:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 115282  bytes 165366971 (165.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62424  bytes 5626572 (5.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f0:92:1c:e4:ce:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 66541  bytes 91494426 (91.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38404  bytes 3996295 (3.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xdec00000-dec20000  

enp1s0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f0:92:1c:e4:ce:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 71912  bytes 99638296 (99.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38378  bytes 3997807 (3.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  memory 0xdeb00000-deb20000  

ib0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 4092
        inet 192.168.3.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        unspec 80-00-00-03-FE-80-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 256  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Bucle local)
        RX packets 1364  bytes 102456 (102.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1364  bytes 102456 (102.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

sudo service networking restart:

```
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status networking.service:

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-07-26 10:10:50 CEST; 9s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Main PID: 17070 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

jul 26 10:10:41 sua systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
jul 26 10:10:41 sua ifup[17070]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
jul 26 10:10:41 sua ifup[17070]: Failed to bring up ib0.
jul 26 10:10:41 sua ifup[17070]: Waiting for bond master bond0 to be ready
jul 26 10:10:41 sua ifup[17070]: sh: echo: I/O error
jul 26 10:10:41 sua ifup[17070]: /sbin/ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.bond0
jul 26 10:10:50 sua systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
jul 26 10:10:50 sua systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

journalctl -xe:

```
jul 26 10:10:41 sua kernel: bond0: Adding slave eno1
jul 26 10:10:41 sua NetworkManager[2284]: <info>  [1501056641.4971] device (eno1): released from master device bond0
jul 26 10:10:41 sua ifup[17070]: sh: echo: I/O error
jul 26 10:10:41 sua kernel: bond0: Enslaving eno1 as an active interface with a down link
jul 26 10:10:41 sua kernel: bond0: option primary: mode dependency failed, not supported in mode balance-rr(0)
jul 26 10:10:41 sua dhclient[17165]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
jul 26 10:10:41 sua dhclient[17165]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
jul 26 10:10:41 sua sh[17108]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
jul 26 10:10:41 sua sh[17108]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
jul 26 10:10:41 sua sh[17108]: All rights reserved.
jul 26 10:10:41 sua sh[17108]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
jul 26 10:10:41 sua dhclient[17165]: All rights reserved.
jul 26 10:10:41 sua dhclient[17165]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
jul 26 10:10:41 sua dhclient[17165]: 
jul 26 10:10:41 sua root[17177]: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
jul 26 10:10:41 sua systemd[1]: Reloading.
jul 26 10:10:41 sua dhclient[17165]: Listening on LPF/bond0/f0:92:1c:e4:ce:7e
jul 26 10:10:41 sua dhclient[17165]: Sending on   LPF/bond0/f0:92:1c:e4:ce:7e
jul 26 10:10:41 sua sh[17108]: Listening on LPF/bond0/f0:92:1c:e4:ce:7e
jul 26 10:10:41 sua sh[17108]: Sending on   LPF/bond0/f0:92:1c:e4:ce:7e
jul 26 10:10:41 sua sh[17108]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
jul 26 10:10:41 sua sh[17108]: DHCPDISCOVER on bond0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x8896661c)
jul 26 10:10:41 sua dhclient[17165]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
jul 26 10:10:41 sua dhclient[17165]: DHCPDISCOVER on bond0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x8896661c)
jul 26 10:10:41 sua kernel: bond0: Adding slave enp1s0
jul 26 10:10:41 sua kernel: bond0: Enslaving enp1s0 as an active interface with a down link
jul 26 10:10:41 sua systemd[1]: Reloading.
jul 26 10:10:41 sua ifup[17070]: /sbin/ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.bond0
jul 26 10:10:44 sua dhclient[17165]: DHCPDISCOVER on bond0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x8896661c)
jul 26 10:10:44 sua sh[17108]: DHCPDISCOVER on bond0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x8896661c)
jul 26 10:10:44 sua NetworkManager[2284]: <info>  [1501056644.8469] device (eno1): link connected
jul 26 10:10:44 sua kernel: e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
jul 26 10:10:44 sua NetworkManager[2284]: <info>  [1501056644.9449] device (bond0): link connected
jul 26 10:10:44 sua kernel: bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno1, 1000 Mbps full duplex
jul 26 10:10:44 sua kernel: bond0: first active interface up!
jul 26 10:10:44 sua kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): bond0: link becomes ready
jul 26 10:10:45 sua NetworkManager[2284]: <info>  [1501056645.9704] device (enp1s0): link connected
jul 26 10:10:45 sua NetworkManager[2284]: <info>  [1501056645.9710] device (enp1s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
jul 26 10:10:45 sua kernel: e1000e: enp1s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
jul 26 10:10:45 sua kernel: bond0: link status definitely up for interface enp1s0, 1000 Mbps full duplex
jul 26 10:10:46 sua avahi-daemon[2248]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface bond0.IPv6 with address fe80::f292:1cff:fee4:ce7e.
jul 26 10:10:46 sua avahi-daemon[2248]: New relevant interface bond0.IPv6 for mDNS.
jul 26 10:10:46 sua avahi-daemon[2248]: Registering new address record for fe80::f292:1cff:fee4:ce7e on bond0.*.
jul 26 10:10:46 sua whoopsie[2302]: [10:10:46] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
jul 26 10:10:47 sua whoopsie[2302]: [10:10:47] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
jul 26 10:10:49 sua dhclient[17165]: DHCPDISCOVER on bond0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x8896661c)
jul 26 10:10:49 sua sh[17108]: DHCPDISCOVER on bond0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x8896661c)
jul 26 10:10:50 sua dhclient[17165]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.148 on bond0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1c669688)
jul 26 10:10:50 sua sh[17108]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.148 on bond0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1c669688)
jul 26 10:10:50 sua sh[17108]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.148 from 192.168.1.1
jul 26 10:10:50 sua dhclient[17165]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.148 from 192.168.1.1
jul 26 10:10:50 sua dhclient[17165]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.148 from 192.168.1.1
jul 26 10:10:50 sua sh[17108]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.148 from 192.168.1.1
jul 26 10:10:50 sua root[17295]: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
jul 26 10:10:50 sua avahi-daemon[2248]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface bond0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.148.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua avahi-daemon[2248]: New relevant interface bond0.IPv4 for mDNS.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua avahi-daemon[2248]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.148 on bond0.IPv4.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua whoopsie[2302]: [10:10:50] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
jul 26 10:10:50 sua systemd-resolved[2733]: Switching to system DNS server 192.168.1.1.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua dhclient[17165]: bound to 192.168.1.148 -- renewal in 3300 seconds.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua sh[17108]: bound to 192.168.1.148 -- renewal in 3300 seconds.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua systemd[1]: Reloading.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua systemd[1]: Reloading.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
jul 26 10:10:50 sua systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jul 26 10:10:50 sua sudo[16832]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

**Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English**